# Not Getting QR Code Data Using AVFoundation Framework

Tags: ios

I used AVFoundation framework delegate methods to read QR Code.It is reading almost all QR codes & giving resulted data for them. But when I try with some QR code(eg. below QR image) , it is predicting that it is QR code but does not give any data for it.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your sample is triggering an internal (C++) exception.. it seems to be getting caught around `[AVAssetCache setMaxSize:]` which suggests either the data in this particular sample is corrupt, or it's just to large for AVFoundation to handle.

As it's an internal exception it is (mostly) failing silently. The exception occurs when you try to extract the `stringValue` from your `AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject`.

So if you test for the existence of your `AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject`, you will get YES, whereas if you test for `stringValue` you will get NO.

```
AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject *readableObject = 
(AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject *)[self.previewLayer      
         transformedMetadataObjectForMetadataObject:metadataObject];

    BOOL foundObject = readableObject != nil; 
     //returns YES

    BOOL foundString = readableObject.stringValue != nil; 
      //returns NO + triggers internal exception
```

It's probably best to test for the string, rather than the object, and ignore any result that returns NO.

*update*

In your comment you ask about native framework solution that will read this barcode. AVFoundation *is* the native framework for barcode reading, so if it fails on your sample, you will have to look for third-party solutions.

`zxing` offers an iOS port but it looks to be old and unsupported.

[zbarSDK](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zbar/) used to be a good solution but also seems to be unsupported past ios4. As AVFoundation now has built-in barcode reading, this is unsurprising.

[This solution](http://www.accusoft.com/barcodemobiledemo.htm) by Accusoft does read the sample but is proprietary and really pricey.

I do wonder about the content of you sample though - it looks either corrupt or some kind of exotic encoding...

[image]

Comment: Hi Foundry, the QR code provided by me is not corrupted.It might have some kind of encoding.But if I scan the same code with zxing library it shows the correct contents.I think, this case is not handled by native AVFoundation framework.

Comment: @Vijay, you are correct - this case is not handled. _perhaps_ it is an edge case or extension in the QRCode specification that is not supported by Apple, and/or a bug in the framework (you could file a [radar](http://radar.apple.com) with Apple). Unfortunately, as Apple now provides a native framework for this task, it is going to get harder to find well-maintained third-party solutions that work for you.